# Melhor jeito para substituir mais de um caractere no php

Tags: php

Estou usando o `str_replace` do *php* para deixar um telefone sem a máscara. Estou fazendo desse jeito, mas queria saber se existe outra função que deixe isso mais objetivo.

```
$fone = str_replace("(", "", $_POST["fone"]);
$fone2 = str_replace(")", "", $fone);
$fone3 = str_replace("-", "", $fone2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com esta mesma função que tás utilizando é possível fazer isso. O `str_replace` aceita um *array* como parâmetro, então é só fazer o seguinte:

```
$fone = str_replace(['(', ')', '-'], '', $_POST['fone']);
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode passar uma array com todos os parâmetros que você quer retirar.

```
$fone = '(01)0000-0000';
$retirar = array("(", ")", "-");
$fone = str_replace($retirar, "", $fone);
echo $fone;
```

ou, passar o array direto na função

```
$fone = '(01)0000-0000';
$fone = str_replace(["(", ")", "-"], "", $fone);
echo $fone;
```

Se quiser saber mais sobre a função sugiro a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)